# Increase the size of a div button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a slideshow of images and need help in increasing the size of the onclick buttons (classes "left" and "right") in the slideshow.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="coasters">
<div class="content">
<img class="img" src="coasters1.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="img" src="coasters2.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="img" src="coasters3.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094; </div>
<div class="right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);}

function currentDiv(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex = n);}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  }

for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" white", "");}

x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " white";}
```

**CSS:**

```
.coasters {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e8e8e8;
}

.img {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.left {
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
}

.content{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
}
```

**I have tried adding a width and height to it but it does not become larger.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand which element's height/ width you are setting here. Your left and right buttons are in a `div` element. So if you specify height and width, this will affect the overall `div` and not it's content.

The buttons are actually text here. So you need to specify the `font-size`. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76crzpr1/) here. Notice the difference in sizes of left and right buttons and then notice the CSS. The `font-size` of `.left` is more hence it appears bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I've added one more parameter in your function.

```
<div class="left" onclick="plusDivs(-1,$(this))">&#10094; </div>
<div class="right" onclick="plusDivs(1,$(this))">&#10095;</div>
```

JS

```
function plusDivs(n,me) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    $(me).attr('style','width:100px');//you may define any width here.
}
```

Hope it help to you.